# Write into file nodemcu lua

Tags: file, variables, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to write into a file and then read its contents the code I am using is:

```
file.remove("CRED.lua")
file.open("CRED.lua","w+")
temp = "PASS = "..pass
file.writeline(temp)
temp = "SSID = "..ssid
file.writeline(temp)
file.flush()
temp = nil
file.close()
```

It seems that the file is created but I when I do this:

```
dofile("CRED.lua")
print(PASS)
print(SSID)
```

I am getting both nil value.
Do you know why?

Comment: `temp = "PASS = "..("%q"):format(pass)`

Answer (score 2):

In the `CRED.lua` file you have :

```
PASS = <password stored in pass variable>
```

As the `<password stored in pass variable>` variable is not set, execution will result setting `PASS` to `nil`.

You need to quote password and ssid, for instance using:

```
file.remove("CRED.lua")
file.open("CRED.lua","w+")
temp = "PASS = \""..pass.."\""
file.writeline(temp)
temp = "SSID = \""..ssid.."\""
file.writeline(temp)
file.flush()
temp = nil
file.close()
```